# php maths calculations not giving correct results

Tags: php, math

I am trying to do some maths to work out free items in php on my shop checkout.

Here is my code:

```
$bugofq = $cart_item['quantity'] * get_free_quantity($cart_item['product_id']);

$deal['freequantity'] = 10;
$deal['itemquantity'] = 5;

if($deal['freequantity'] >= 1 && $deal['itemquantity'] >= 1 && $cart_item['quantity'] > $deal['itemquantity']){
  $bugofq = $cart_item['quantity'] + $deal['freequantity']; 
}
```

So basically i am querying my database to see if a certain product exists. If it does i am then checking to see if it has any offers applied.

The above example has an offer of "buy 5 products, get 10 free".

My if statement above calculates this correctly so the total products is then 15.

However, if i add 10 products to my cart i should end up with a total of 30 products ( 5+10 + 5+10 = 30), but i end up with 20. This also happens if i add any amount of the 5. So if i add 20 products to my cart i would expect to see 60, the origial 20 and 40 free, Bu ti end up with 30.

Is there anything obviously wrong with my above cal

Comment: if 5 product is added then total product in cart is (5 + 10(free)) = 15 and if 10 product is added then total product in cart is (10 + 10(free for first 5) + 10(free for next five)) = 30?

Comment: Did any of the answers meet your needs? If so, could you mark the answer of your choice as accepted or else leave a comment?

Answer (score 0):

In your all described cases your if statement condition evaluates to true, so following code `$bugofq = $cart_item['quantity'] + $deal['freequantity'];` is running and as a result it is adding value of `$deal['freequantity']` to `$cart_item['quantity']` only once i.e. in your case it will always add 10 to the value that is why for 5 you are getting 15, for 10 you are getting 20 instead of 30, for 20 you are getting 30 instead of 60.

For correct calculation you should calculate the multiplier `$c= floor($cart_item['quantity'] / $deal['itemquantity'])`.  `$c` shows how many times you should apply free items package, hence the result would be `$bugofq = $cart_item['quantity'] + ( $c * $deal['freequantity']);`.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you have only accounts for one time addition of the free count. To do it correctly you need to see how many times that addition should be applied. This you can do with the following code:

```
$bugofq = $cart_item['quantity']; // default case
if($deal['itemquantity'] >= 1){ // deal present
    $bugofq += $deal['freequantity'] *
            intdiv($cart_item['quantity'], $deal['itemquantity']); 
}
```